# Customized navigation controller toolbar is one pixel upper than the bottom of iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I had to customize UIViewController and Used following codes to customize the UIViewController toolbar at the bottom

```
[self.navigationController.toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"List/footer.png"].CGImage scale:2 orientation:UIImageOrientationDown] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.toolbar setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny];
    [self.navigationController.toolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

[image]

As it is obvious in screenshot picture there is one white pixel under the customized toolbar.
How can I remove the pixel?

Comment: what does "List/footer.png" look like?

Comment: It's a simple gray rectangle which is background of toolbar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple answer but I have same situation lots of times :) Try to control image **List/footer.png** it can has 1px transparency bottom of itself?

Another situation is in iOS project I have never give a path like **List/**

Also my advice is if you want to give a shadow don't use image instead of this use QuartzCore framework and layer.shadow.

Comment: How to give 1px transparency?

Comment: Use Photoshop and open footer.png after that check it has already 1px transparency bottom of image?